# Explicit representation of subsets of M := { 1, {a,b}, { {1}, a, b} }

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I am new to naïve set theory and I have been struggling with the following question as I am not sure which Venn diagrams and related logical concepts represent the sets (including the ones to be depicted explicitly).

> Given the objects a, b and sets ***M*** := { 1, {a,b}, { {1}, a, b} }
>   and ***N*** := ***M*** \ {1} depict the following sets explicitly and explain
>   why your solution is correct:
>   ***A*** := { A| A  ⊆ *M* },     ***B*** :={A ∈ ***A*** | A has two or three elements}.

I should also add that repetition of objects in a set is not allowed, so {1, 1, 2, 3, 3} is not accepted as a set according to the book and the professor.

One of the main points of my confusion is that I am not sure if the objects a, b are represented as a conjunction of two sets or whether the sets containing a, b are totally separate from each other as subsets of ***M***.

I would appreciate an answer that also shows how to approach the problem as my aim is not only to answer this specific question but also develop a deeper understanding of similar problems and cases. The question is originally formulated in a language of which I am not a native speaker and I translated it it into English.

Comment: ***M*** has $3$ elements, so $8$ subsets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two sets, $\{a,b\}$ and $\{\{1\},a,b\}$ are elements of $M$, the *elements* of those sets don't matter at all.

Use the symbol $W = \{a,b\}$ and $V=\{\{1\},a,b\}$ and then $M = \{1, W,V\}$.  That's a set with $3$ elements.

So $A:=\{K|K\subset M\} = \mathscr P (M)$ will have $2^3=8$ elements based on whether $1,W$ or $V$ are in the subset.  So the $8$ subsets are:

$A = \{$

$\emptyset, \{1\}, \{W\}, \{V\}, $

$\{1,W\}, \{1,V\}, \{W, V\},$

$\{1,W,V\}$

$\}$.

And $B$ being those with $2$ or more elements will be

$B=\{$

$\{1,W\}, \{1,V\}, \{W, V\},\{1,W,V\}$

$\}$.

.....

In other words

$A = \{$

$\emptyset, \{1\}, \{\{a,b\}\}, \{\{\{1\},a,b\}\}, $

$\{1,\{a,b\}\}, \{1,\{\{1\},a,b\}\}, \{\{a,b\}, \{\{1\},a,b\}\},$

$\{1,\{a,b\},\{\{1\},a,b\}\}$

$\}$.

And

$B=\{$

$\{1,\{\{a,b\}\}\}, \{1,\{\{\{1\},a,b\}\}\}, \{\{\{a,b\}\}, \{\{\{1\},a,b\}\}\},\{1,\{\{a,b\}\},\{\{\{1\},a,b\}\}\}$

$\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much.